# Flutter converting listview to listview.builder

Tags: listview, flutter

I was looking at this example in google codelabs.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#10

In it, there is this particular listview with the following code:

```
Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
  return ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
    children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
  );
}
```

I am interested to convert the Listview to using Listview.builder but somehow I could not figure out how I could do it.  Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have to do is click on the `ListView` by pressing ctrl and then you will navigate to source code for that and just scroll and see the `ListView.builder` named constructor. There will see everything you can do with and some doc comments.

Comment: Anyone encountered sluggish issue with listview.builder?  Sometimes it can be hard to scroll.

Comment: Thats mean is it slow or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
             return _buildListItem(context,snapshot[index]);
                       }
          itemCount: snapshot.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0), 
          );
    }
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
        itemCount: snapshot.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return _buildListItem(context, snapshot[index]);
        }
    );
}
```